# Call js function from python

Tags: javascript, python

I have a js file with:

```
function hi (){
console.log("Hello world!");
return 'hello';
}
```

And I want to call this function from my python code. I'm using the naked lib, so I run something like this:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js
response = execute_js('node.js')
print response
```

But I want to run this specific method hi(), not execute the script 'Node.js' (because it does nothing by itself). I also wan't to get the returned value.

I'm able to use another lib if necessary.

Comment: Why don't you make a script that _only_ calls `hi()` in your other one, then run that with execute_js?

Comment: It's a good approach.. I didn't think about it. But to get the returned value I would need to write it into a file and read it in python, right?

Comment: I would assume so, I've never used the library before. It would get out of control though if you wanted to call more methods. Perhaps [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS) might suit your needs.

Comment: I've tried this lib. But I can call the function from the file? I saw I can compile a code (just like the example) and run it.. but I need to get this function from a js file... I would need to read this file as string and give it as parameter?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Node.js... That's plain Javascript

Comment: It's similar to this question.. but his question is embracing. I want to call a js function from a js file and get the output from this function in python. I've tried the suggestions from this question, but didn't work for me.